# Luci openWRT UCI firewall rule update without position number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, firewall, openwrt

Hey all I have been trying find some code that would allow me to update my firewall rule via the UCI.

The way I am currently adding the new rule is like this:

```
uci add firewall rule
uci set firewall.@rule[21].name='B Macbook Air'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].src='lan'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].family='ipv4'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].src_ip='192.168.1.227'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].src_mac='00:00:00:00:00:00'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].dest='wan'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].proto='all'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].target='REJECT'
uci set firewall.@rule[21].enabled='1'
uci commit firewall
```

This produces the correct rule inside **luci (branch (git-22.347.45520-d30ab74))**:

[image]

The way I update one of the rules' enabled or disable is this:

```
uci set firewall.@rule[21].name="B Macbook Air"
uci set firewall.@rule[21].enabled="1"
uci commit firewall
```

Which works as expected but I am wondering if there's a way too just call the firewall rules name instead of needing to know the position (ie: [21])?

Like this:

```
uci set firewall.@rule.name="B Macbook Air"
uci set firewall.@rule.enabled="1"
uci commit firewall
```

But of course the above does not work. Gives an error of

> root@turris:~# uci set firewall.@rule.name="B Macbook Air"
>
> uci: Invalid argument

Is this possible to do?